# how to compress images in webview before uploading on server

Tags: android, image, webview, upload, compression

**I want to upload image in webview, but i need compress image before upload on server.**

Please help to add code in my code as given below

**this is webview code, please ADD YOUR code in my code**

i am learning to make webview app

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String mCM;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
private final static int FCR = 1;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            LoadWeb();
        }
    });

    LoadWeb();


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (mUMA != null) {
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e("Webview", "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;
        }

    });//Image close
}


public void LoadWeb() {

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
    swipe.setRefreshing(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

        }


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("google.com")) {

                return false;

            }


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            //Hide the SwipeReefreshLayout

            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }

    });
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }



}

class Browser_home extends WebViewClient {

    Browser_home() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        setTitle(view.getTitle());

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}


public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
    this.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "*/*");
}

public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
    this.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, null);
}

public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    i.setType("*/*");
    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Uri[] results = null;
        //Check if response is positive
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUMA) {
                    return;
                }
                if (intent == null) {
                    //Capture Photo if no image available
                    if (mCM != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUMA = null;
    } else {
        if (requestCode == FCR) {
            if (null == mUM) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUM = null;
        }
    }
}

// Create an image file
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);


}//Image close
```

}

some api depreciated  message during debug app creating